# x86 Assembly: At the end of the program get a strange output

Tags: assembly, x86, background, bios, vga

I wrote a simple code for change the color of the screen but at the and of the instructions i get a strange output.
I know exist better ways to change the color but is just a test.

The program work fine but at the end i receive a strange output.
I had the same problem on Windows 2000 and Windows XP.
Where is the error?

```
MOV AH,00H
MOV AL,13H
INT 10H

MOV BH,00H
MOV DX,0000H
OuterLoop:
MOV CX,0000H
InnerLoop:
MOV AL,2AH
MOV AH,0CH
INT 10H
INC CX
CMP CX,013FH
JBE InnerLoop
INC DX
CMP DX,00C7H
JBE OuterLoop

MOV AH,00H
INT 21H
```

[background color work fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5A13.png)
[output at the end of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxBkg.png)

Comment: Well, `2AH` happens to be the ascii code of `*`. Looks like windows switched back to text mode for you but left the video memory unchanged. I assume if you do whatever you want in your program it will work normally. Also consider explicitly switching back to text mode before terminating.

Comment: Forgot to add `mov al,03h` to switch back to text mode after the loop? And `int 10h` not `int 21h`

Comment: It's only polite to read the mode current mode on entry and restore the original mode at exit.

Comment: I solved the problem using MOV AH,00H MOV AL,03H INT 10H at the end of the program. Thank you!